# Using Wordpress with Nodejs and Express

Tags: node.js, wordpress, express

I set up a Node.js server that serves a database and need to integrate it into Wordpress. Is there a way to intregrate a [simple express page](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html) and would like to display the "Hello World" page on a site hosted by Wordpress. Is there a good, solid way to handle get request in Node.js and send the result to the Wordpress site?

#### EDIT:

I noticed the [Wordpress](https://www.npmjs.com/package/wordpress) module, but as far as I can tell, it doesn't have the functionality that express does (e.g. `res.redirect('/')` or something like `res.send('Test')`). I need a way to: integrate my already made express server to send to Wordpress.

Comment: WordPress uses PHP and MySQL for its front-end and back-end. Are you trying to use WordPress as a headless CMS or are you trying to show content which you get from your express app in your WordPress website? For the first scenario, you should use WordPress API and for the second one, you need to make some kind of plugins inside WordPress which connects to your express app, grabs info and show it in your website using PHP.

Comment: @ImanGM the latter scenario. I am trying to show content that would (in a Node.js environment) be shown through Node.js's express module. Thanks!

Comment: @ImanGM yes, as @ divinelemon said, i am trying to show content through wordpress like express would.

Comment: @imaginate So, you need to make the API on Express side, then use a plugin or some function in your WordPress theme to connect to your Express API and get the result, then show it in your WordPress site...

Comment: oh, I never thought of this. Thanks!